How can I start a process based on the information sent from another computer?
Background
I have two computers, A and B. These computers are connected through the use of an ethernet cable where A is connected wireless to the router while B is in monitor mode and is therefore not associated with any access point. The intention is to capture raw encrypted 802.11 frames sent between A and the access point. I want to automate this process by sending a signal from A to B over the ethernet cable such that B can automatically start capturing traffic using airodump-ng right before A fetches data. Computer A would also send a signal of when to stop and what the traffic B observes is (see code below). Computer A uses  with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s: and s.sendall(f"xxx".encode()) to send data to computer B.
Problem
I am able to use ncat to observe that the client actually sends the different messages over the ethernet cable. This is then displayed in the terminal of B. However, I am not able to read those messages and start other processes based on the traffic I receive. Based on my knowledge, I guess it has something to do with how the process of listening to the port works. After the script from computer A is finished, every single command sent to B is displayed in print("Received message:", message).
Code
This is the code that I have. I have tried some variations of this, but the code has always been more or less the same. Then intention is to use ncat with the following options and based on the received information perform an action using if/elif statements.
import subprocess

def handle_messages():
    # Start ncat listening on the specified port
    ncat_process = subprocess.Popen(["ncat", "-l", "<ip_address>", "-p", "<port>"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

    while True:
        # Read a single line from ncat process's stdout
        message = ncat_process.stdout.readline().strip()

        print("Received message:", message)

        # Process the received message
        if message == "START_CAPTURE":
            print("Starting capture...")
            subprocess.Popen(["airodump-ng", "--channel", "<my_channel>", "--bssid", "<my_bssid>", "--write", "capture", "<interface>"])
        elif message == "STOP_CAPTURE":
            print("Stopping capture...")
            subprocess.Popen(["pkill", "airodump-ng"])
        elif message.startswith("Answer:"):
            with open("answer.txt", "a") as file:
                file.write(answer)
        elif message == "STOP_SCRIPT":
            print("Stopping script...")
            break

    # Terminate the ncat process
    ncat_process.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    handle_messages()

Question
I am wondering: How I can read single "commands" sent from A to B in real time, and start and end processes based on the information sent?
Ps: I have been using stackoverflow for many years, but never posted anything. Feel free to guide me if there are any issues with the format of the question or lack of information needed to provide a solid answer to the question. Thanks!

Your code basically works for me (on my linux box). (I don't have aerodump-ng so replaced that with an echo command, but otherwise, the scaffolding is fine.) A couple of suggestions: (1) It would be simpler to just create your own listening socket instead of having ncat do it for you, (2) store the return value from Popen of aerodump-ng as ae_proc, say, and STOP_CAPTURE can simply do ae_proc.terminate, (3) should check for empty message after reading from the pipe, (4) your code refers to undefined variable answer but that doesn't harm anything unless you send "ANSWER"
